# Why is my CSS layout different to my original template?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here is the template that I have been using

http://themes.truethemes.net/Karma-HTML/content-pricing-tables.html

Here is my test application

http://eplay.herokuapp.com/

I haven't changed too much other than colors and column widths.  However I appear to have broken some layout elements and after a lot of fiddling I still can't seem to fix.  It's just a few subtle things but I would still like to get it done properly.

The first thing is that in the template the top border (above basic free, extra etc) is rendered smoothly and beautifully.  I have done something to introduce double and triple borders whichs I cannot remove.  The second thing is in my test version above '1000 inboxes' and under '24/7 online support' I have somehow introduced an indentation effect whichs looks a bit out of place to me.  I'm pretty sure it's only a few lines I need to tweak but unfortunately I cannot figure out which lines.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this extra line of code thats making the double borders:

```
<div class="hr_top_link"></div>
```

If I understood correctly, the indent would be there in both demos.

Hope this helps!